# How to display .entry-content CSS on Wordpress home page?

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I'm adding extra content to the home page on a Wordpress theme (Pitch) and most of my custom CSS works - everything except any styles I added to '.entry-content'. I checked the theme's style.css and still, none of the '.entry-content' styles are displaying.

For example, I use this code and anything within < h1 > looks the same as if it were body text:

```
.entry-content h1 {
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
```

Is there a way to fix this that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: try adding !important `font-size:1.8em !important;`

Comment: Might be a silly question, but you do have a div or other element on the home page with the class "entry-content" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the theme styles, I discovered that the theme I was using actually had it's own !important declarations that were overriding my code.